# How to configure vsftpd so anyone can upload to a specified directory?

Tags: ftp

I installed vsftpd on Linux Mint, I changed some settings to the configuration file so it permits anonymous users, however I want to redirect them to a certain directory where they can upload files. I'm just confused among the settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the ftp directory, edit /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf and add the following line:

local_root=/home/ftp

This will change the ftp root to /home/ftp, but this can be any directory as long as it exists.  Don't forget to restart vsftpd after the change.